# using ICE Tar library to tar large size files

Tags: java, byte, arrays, tar

I am using ICE tar library to make tar files.

My code snippet is,

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import com.ice.tar.TarEntry;
import com.ice.tar.TarOutputStream;


public class Util {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    tar();
}   
    public static void tar(){
        try{
      // Output file stream   
    FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream( "f:/test/test.tar" );   
    // Create a TarOutputStream   
    TarOutputStream out = new TarOutputStream( new BufferedOutputStream( dest ) );   
    // Files to tar   
    File[] filesToTar=new File[2];   filesToTar[0]=new File("f:/test/myfile1.txt");   
    filesToTar[1]=new File("f:/test/myfile2.txt");  
    for(File f:filesToTar){      
        out.putNextEntry(new TarEntry(f));     
        BufferedInputStream origin = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream( f ));     
        int count;     
        byte data[] = new byte[2048];     
        while((count = origin.read(data)) != -1) {        
            out.write(data, 0, count);     
            }     
        out.flush();      
        origin.close();  
        }  
    out.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

However this works only for small sized files. When i try to tar large size files i get the following error stating,

```
java.io.IOException: request to write '2048' bytes exceeds size in header of '1495040' bytes
    at com.ice.tar.TarOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
```

When i tried changing

`byte data[] = new byte[2048];` to `byte data[] = new byte[origin.available()];`

i got,

```
java.io.IOException: request to write '1495040' bytes exceeds size in header of '1495040' bytes
    at com.ice.tar.TarOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
```

I couldnt able to find why this happens. Please help.

**EDIT:**
The large size files which i try to tar is itself a tar file.

Comment: I just tried your code (even with the tar file inside) and it works correcly with javatar 2.5 and ~ 200 megs size.

Comment: My Mistake..I kept the previously generated erroraneous tar file and after deleting i got it resolved.